# How to write a new column to csv when webscraping?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'd like to get some quick help on writing this webscraping program. So far it's scraping things correctly, but I'm having trouble writing it to a csv file.

I'm scraping two things from each reviewer: Review score AND written review

I'd like to write the review score into the first column, and the written review into the second column. However, writerow only does it row by row.

Appreciate any help on this! :)

```
import os, requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get URL of the page
URL = ('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g294265-d2149128-Reviews-Gardens_by_the_Bay-Singapore.html')

with open('GardensbytheBay.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # Looping until the 5th page of reviews
    for pagecounter in range(3):

        # Request get the first page
        res = requests.get(URL)
        res.raise_for_status

        # Download the html of the first page
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
        # Match it to the specific tag for all 5 ratings
        reviewElems = soup.findAll('img', {'class': ['sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s50', 'sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s40', 'sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s30', 'sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s20', 'sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s10']})
        reviewWritten = soup.findAll('p', {'class':'partial_entry'})

        if reviewElems:
            for row, rows in zip(reviewElems, reviewWritten): 
                review_text = row.attrs['alt'][0] 
                review2_text = rows.get_text(strip=True).encode('utf8', 'ignore').decode('latin-1')
                writer.writerow([review_text]) 
                writer.writerow([review2_text])

            print('Writing page', pagecounter + 1)
        else:
            print('Could not find clue.')

        # Find URL of next page and update URL
        if pagecounter == 0:
            nextLink = soup.select('a[data-offset]')[0]
        elif pagecounter != 0:
            nextLink = soup.select('a[data-offset]')[1]

        URL = 'http://www.tripadvisor.com' + nextLink.get('href')

print('Download complete')
```

Comment: `writerow([review_text, review2_text])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the review score and text in the same row but different columns with:

```
writer.writerow([review_text, review2_text])
```

Your initial approach takes each of the items as a separate row and writes them in succession which is not what you want.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas dataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
csv_file = pd.read_csv('GardensbytheBay.csv')
csv_file.insert(idx, cloname, value)
csv_input.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```